# Migrating from posterous to jekyll gives a 500

Tags: ruby, jekyll, posterous

when i try to use jekyll's importer to grab my posterous blog, i get the following error:

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/migrators/posterous"; Jekyll::Posterous.process("me@gmail.com", "mypass", "myblogid")'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2632:in `error!': 500 "Internal Server Error" (Net::HTTPFatalError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/posterous.rb:26:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/posterous.rb:32:in `process'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas? I tried running a http debugging proxy to peek at the traffic to get an idea what's going wrong, but i couldn't figure out how to get ruby to use the proxy. Any suggestions there either?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, in the end i used the different migrator here:

```
https://github.com/pepijndevos/jekyll/blob/patch-1/lib/jekyll/migrators/posterous.rb
```

I just had to comment out the image-scraping code.